# Polls with images table schema?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

I am trying to create a poll application that may have images and may have no images at all. If it does have images, then it can have many or just one. For example, each choice may have an image or there may be only 1 image for all choices. Here's a good example of what I want to create: [Opinion Stage](https://www.opinionstage.com/showcase?o=wp35e8).

Here's the table schema I'm thinking of:

```
Questions //Table of all questions with total votes to avoid querying all user votes
  -id
  -user_id (foreign key to users)
  -title
  -description
  -total_votes
  -date

Choices  //Table of all question choices, each will have vote_count to avoid querying all voting_history each time.
  -id
  -question_id (foreign key to questions)
  -choice
  -vote_count

voting_history //Table that shows which user voted for what.
  -id
  -choice_id (foreign key to choices)
  -user_id (foreign key to users)
  -date

Images  //Table that gives the images for the choices
  -id
  -question_id (foreign key to Questions)
  -img
```

Let's say we have only 1 image, then the first choice will have an image, but the rest of the images will not have any rows in the image table. If we have 2 choices and there are 2 images, then each choice will have an image.

**More in depth about what each row in each table does:**
In `Questions`, `user_id` is the field that represents who made the question, the `title` is the title of the question, the `description` is the description of the question. For example, we could have a title that says this: `Which car is better?` and a description that says this: `I like both, but I have to go with the BMW.` the `total_votes` is the total number of votes the question has for example if could have 50 votes, and `date` is when the question was posted.

In the `Choices` table, `question_id` tells us which question this choice belongs to, `choice` gives the choice to the question, using our previous car question example, we could have a choice that says `BMW` and another choice that says `Audi`. `vote_count` is the number of votes each question has. For example, we could have 25 votes for BMW and 25 votes for Audi (hence the 50 total_votes in the Questions table.)

In `voting_history`, `choice_id` tells us which choice the user picked and `user_id` tells us which user it was. `date` is the time the vote was made.

In `Images`, `question_id` is which question the image belongs to, `img` is the image URL of the question. To give a better understanding of this table, here's an example poll:
[image]

The title is Ronaldo vs. Messi, with no description, total_votes is 50, with 2 choices, and it has 2 images. These images will be stored in the `Images` table. We would have a row for each image. Now let's say we have this poll:
[image]

We would have only 1 image in the `Images` table for this question. Is this a good way to build a table schema like this? Is it efficient?

Comment: Your paragraph re how the tables are used are unclear. Eg "if we have only 1 image ... the rest of the images" doesn't make sense; there are no other images if there's only 1. Instead explain for each table what a row in it says about the application. Give some example data. PS It's time to read a textbook on information modeling & database design.

Comment: What is the datatype of `img`?  Is is just a URL pointing to the image?  Or a `MEDIUMBLOB`?

Comment: @philipxy I don't think you understand what I'm asking for. Please take a look at the link and the description of each table i've provided. A question will always have at least 2 choices, but a question might have no images, 1 image, 2 images (1 image above each choice), etc.

Comment: @RickJames It is just a URL

Comment: I just told you I don't understand. But it is because you are poorly describing, and I told you what will give a good description.

Comment: @philipxy I just updated the question with more details, please let me know if you need anything else

Answer (score 0):

> Let's say we have only 1 image, then the first choice will have an image, but the rest of the images will not have any rows in the image table. If we have 2 choices and there are 2 images, then each choice will have an image.

That is a recipe for inconsistency. In the Ronaldo/Messi example, you probably want to make sure that the images match the buttons/Choices, and not rely on ordering of surrogate keys(?) for that to happen. That suggests having a foreign key from Images to Choices, not Questions.

For the second example, the image is not related to any particular choice, but to the Question itself. That suggests a separate table for such images.

Comment: Why should we also declare question_id as key when we can see which question the image is from, from the choice?

Comment: Sorry, I got a bit ahead of myself. It might make sense to have a composite key in Choices, consisting of question_id and a choice number (choice 1, choice 2...), and refer to this key from voting_history, so you can easily constrain each user to answer each question at most once. The FK from Images could also refer to this (and also use the corresponding columns as its own key, assuming at most one image per choice). See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51022843/). But you're not directly asking about keys and constraints, so I'll edit it out.